# How to make splash screen on application icon click?

Tags: android

In my application when am running the application my splash screen is coming. splash screen is not coming from icon click. I want to show splash screen when I open my application from application icon without running the application. This is onCreate() method code in SplasScreen.java class. This is first class in my manifest file.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    mLogo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    context = this;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent j = new Intent();
            j.setClass(context, Login.class);
            startActivity(j);
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: try putting setContextView to the bottom

Comment: How's that possible show Splash screen.java and mainfest.xml file

Comment: On behalf of your users: Please don't make us wait 2 seconds for absolutely no reason. If you have some work that needs to be done then by all means do it in the background while you show a splash screen. If you are showing a splash screen just for the sake of doing so you are wasting the users time IMO.

Comment: Yes. I want that the splash screen activity to start when you press the app icon.I want to  show a splash screen just for the sake of doing

Comment: @SriramanRanjan If you must implement a *useless* splashscreen [please follow this tutorial](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) The author gives some good reasons why what you are doing is a bad idea. But also gives a thorough tutorial of how to set up your splash screen in what is the most "correct" manner. Though there is no truly "correct" way to needlessly waste peoples time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tim, they are wasting users time for no reason unless something is working in the background.
Anyway maybe this tutorial will be of use:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuS_airZgKM

The videos have have helped me alot in the past :)

Comment: Its working now from same code above. Actually by mistake i had given code on Back Button.